# Access the Repeater.Item.Count value within a codebehind method

Tags: c#, methods, repeater, code-behind

I have a repeater on my page:

```
<asp:Repeater id="attachmentsRepeater" runat="server">
    <HeaderTemplate>
        <% 
        if (attachmentsRepeater.Items.Count > 0) {
            if (attachmentsRepeater.Items.Count == 1) {
                Response.Write("<h3>Attachment</h3>");
                Response.Write("<p>");
            } else {
                Response.Write("<h3>Attachments</h3>");
                Response.Write("<ul>");
            }
        }
        %>
    </HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <%# OutputAttachment(Container)%>
    </ItemTemplate>  
    <FooterTemplate>
        <% 
        if (attachmentsRepeater.Items.Count > 0) {
            if (attachmentsRepeater.Items.Count == 1) {
                Response.Write("</p>");
            } else {
                Response.Write("</ul>");
            }
        }
        %>
    </FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

The original ItemTemplate code looked like this:

```
<ItemTemplate>
    <%
    if (attachmentsRepeater.Items.Count > 0) {
        if (attachmentsRepeater.Items.Count > 1) {
            Response.Write("<li>");
        }
        %>
        <a href="<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "location") %>">
            <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "name") %>
        </a>
        <%
        if (attachmentsRepeater.Items.Count > 1) {
            Response.Write("<li>");
        }
    }
    %>
</ItemTemplate>
```

In the codebehind, I would like to access the number of Items in the Repeater (line 4):

```
public string OutputAttachment(RepeaterItem Container) {
    string returnValue = "";
    Repeater ContainerParent = (Repeater)Container.Parent;
    if (attachmentsRepeater.Items.Count > 0) {
        if (attachmentsRepeater.Items.Count > 1) {
            returnValue += "<li>";
        }
        returnValue += "<a href=\"" + DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "location");
        if (DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "location").ToString().EndsWith("/")) {
            returnValue += DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "name");
        }
        returnValue += ">" + DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "name") + "</a>";
        if (attachmentsRepeater.Items.Count > 1) {
            returnValue += "</li>";
        }
    }
    return returnValue;
}
```

The code that is output is

```
<h3>Attachment</h3>
<p> </p>
```

From this output I know that Item.Count == 1 since there is output, the H3 is singular and there is a P tag. If Item.Count > 1, H3 would be plural and there would be a UL tag.

Is this codebehind method being run before the data is bound? Any workarounds for this? Thanks for your help.

This was working for me before, but I had to change it to fulfill a new requirement, which is when it stopped working.

Answer (score 1):

The best place to do your data binding is in the code behind in the page_load event or some other event that is fired when the page is first created.

That way you can control when the data is bound - and you can call the OuputAttachment method after you have bound your data - and you can be sure that the data actually exists.

Comment: I already have this in the Page_Load event in the codebehind:`this.attachmentsRepeater.DataSource = this.articleAttachments;
this.attachmentsRepeater.DataBind();`  Should it go into another event? Which one?

Comment: it's fine in page_load - when are you calling the OutputAttachment method?

Comment: OutputAttachment() is called in the .aspx page as part of the repeater control. The rest of the .aspx page displays various bits of related information (not that it matters, just trying to give some context).

Comment: are you sure there is data in the repeater control? Try inspecting the collection of items in the repeater

Comment: I've updated the code above with the original working ItemTemplate code. It outputs one attachment (as it should). Is there any way to modify `DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "location")` or assign its value to a variable?